# JavaScript While Loop with if-else if-else and counter

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, counter

I am new to JavaScript. I was taking some tutorials and tried to make a code which printed the multiples of 10 up to 120. It should not print 100, and show a message after 120.But for some reason, it doesn't work. On running the code, nothing on the page is displayed, not even other text. Please Help!

```
var z = 10;
while (z<150){
    if (z==100){
        document.write("Cannot print 100!");
        continue;
    }
    else if (z==130){
        document.write("Cannot print after 120!");
        break;
    }
    document.write(z+"<br>");
    z+=10;
}
```

Comment: You should probably start with `var z = 0` and because you have a break statement, you can change your while clause to `while (true)`.

Comment: Debug your code. Step through it line by line.

Comment: @Luka, still didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because iterator won't to beyong 90 as condition says in while loop. Make that condition z<=120.

Or

```
while(z <= 120) {
  if (z==100) {
    // cant print 100 z = z + 10;
    continue;
  }
  // print z
  z = z + 10;
}
```

Comment: How would that account for no output at all?

Comment: Thank you Man! Putting  `z+=10` after `if(z==100){}` did help!

Comment: @MrigankPawagi Please accept this as answer instead of changing title to solved

Answer (score 1):

1) You should ensure to declare the variable (var z = 0;) or you will encounter an "undefined variable" error.

2) The while loop condition is wrong, because your loop will never print 110 and 120 with `z < 100`. You can set `while(z < 130)` or `while(true)`.

3) I also suggest you to change your break condition from `z == 130` to `z >= 130`, so you're not going into an endless loop in case you decide to change counter increment.

4) Finally, it is a common mistake in `while` loops to place counter increment in wrong line. In this case when `z` reaches 100 it will never go on.

```js
var z = 0;
while (z < 130){
    z+=10;

    if (z==100){
        console.log("Cannot print 100!");
        continue;
    }
    else if (z>=130){
        console.log("Cannot print after 120!");
        break;
    }
    console.log(z);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Bro! The problem was just with the counter. All I had to do was to put `z+=10` after `if(z==100){}`

Comment: Happy you solved :) Placing `z+=10` after `while` condition you avoid redundant line code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=10;i<=120;i+=10){
   if(i===100){
        continue;
   }
   document.write(i+'\n');
}

or with while loop
var j=10;
while(j<=120){
     if(j===100){
         j+=10;
         continue;
     }
     document.write(j+'\n');
     j+=10;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Providing context and descriptions make your answers more useful to a wider audience.